# {sale_end_date} not working (tag not recognised?)

Tags: expresso-store

I can't get sale_start_date or sale_end_date to work in expresso store.

The following code (inside {exp:store_product})

```
{if on_sale}
<strong>På salg: <strike>{regular_price}</strike> {price}</strong><br>
<em>Du sparer {you_save}</em><br>
<em>Salget varer til {sale_end_date format="%m-%d-%Y"}</em>
{if:else}
<strong>Pris: {price}</strong>
{/if}
```

simply outputs {sale_end_date format="%m-%d-%Y"} as plain text exactly as is. It doesn't seem to be a recognized tag. All other tags seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? I can't see anything else in the docs.

Comment: What version of Store and EE are you using?

Comment: Store 2.3.1 and EE 2.8.1

Comment: What happens if you output {sale_end_date} without the formatting param?

Comment: Same result. Outputs as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this variable never made it into Store 2 even though it is in the docs. Email support and we will take a look and getting this fixed.

** Edit v2.3 doesn't have this variable for a reason. With Store 2 you can have multiple sales per product, so there is no single variable that would work. We will need to add a new feature in an upcoming version to make it work.

Comment: Also ran into this now and can see there isn't actually an attribute like sale_start_date or sale_end_date parsed in the Product.toTagArray() function.

Can understand why this is difficult to achieve, because products and sales are completely separate so that a product can belong to any discounts or sales.

Maybe in the mean time it can be removed from the docs, because it is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best solution, because it will just use the last sale's start and end date if there's multiple sales and discounts, but it is better than nothing and most sites will only run one sale at a time.

In store/src/Store/Service/ProductsService.php just below the line (+- line 248)

```
$product->on_sale = true;
```

Add:

```
// HACK: added sale start and end date
$product->sale_start_date = isset($sale['start_date']) ? $sale['start_date'] : NULL;
$product->sale_end_date = isset($sale['end_date']) ? $sale['end_date'] : NULL;
```